# Python start all Threads from doulbe FOR LOOP

Tags: python, multithreading, readline

I have this kind of scenario:

```
threads = []
for wordToScan in wordsList:
    dictionaryFileOpen = open(dictionaryFile, "r")

    for i in range(10):
        threads.append(Thread(target=words_Scan_Start, args=(dictionaryFileOpen, wordToScan)))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

def words_Scan_Start(dictionaryFile, wordToScan):
    while True:
        sub_word = dictionaryFile.readline()
        if not sub_word:
            break
        #... Here is some actions.
```

Now I need to start all these threads at once(10 threads each for every `wordToScan in wordsList`).

Every `wordToScan in wordsList:` should use `dictionaryFileOpen` in 10 threads but without moving `.readline()` for the other `wordToScan in wordsList:` that working at the same time. Also, I can't understand where is to close the `dictionaryFileOpen`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have it done:

```
threads = []
for wordToScan in wordsList:
    wordThread = []
    dictionaryFileOpen = open(dictionaryFile, "r")

    for i in range(10):
        wordThread.append(Thread(target=words_Scan_Start, args=(dictionaryFileOpen, wordToScan)))
    threads.append(wordThread)

for thread in threads:
    for wordThread in thread:
        wordThread.start()
for thread in threads:
    for wordThread in thread:
        wordThread.join()
    dictionaryFileOpen.close()

def words_Scan_Start(dictionaryFile, wordToScan):
    while True:
        sub_word = dictionaryFile.readline()
        if not sub_word:
            break
        #... Here is some actions.
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

You should not read file from several threads. This involves following considerations:

1. Objects which are accessed from several threads must be thread safe. File is not thread safe. So you must guard all places where you use it with mutex.
2. Reading from the disk is quite a slow process. A single thread can handle it with great margin.
3. Linear read is much faster than random read. So it is effective to read it from a single thread.

So general approach is to read the file from one thread and then dispatch the processing fork for other threads. And if you can do the work in one thread it is better just to do it so, because it is much simpler. Make multithreaded applications only when you really need them.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, and I am using Lock() wherever Threads touching "thread-unsafe" shared resources. But the reason I'm using a file is only because `.readline()`. I don't know how to iterate through lines with pointing cursor on the next line every time some thread is using it(`.readline()` can do it). Or how to make every thread use only "next unused" item in a list.

Comment: Make worker threads which take lines from queue (https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and process them. Then make one reader thread which reads lines and pushes them in-to the queue.

Comment: Thanx. Queue worked out for threads with one `wordToScan in wordsList:`. But it didn't helped when I tried to start few `wordToScan in wordsList:` in separated threads which used common Queue. Can you show an example with the code I noticed?

Comment: Each `wordToScan in wordsList:` should use 10 threads to make actions with only one Queue. Each `wordToScan in wordsList:` should do it at the same time when the other ones do.